# Как построить график любой функции с помощью библиотеки JFreeChart?

Tags: java, алгоритм, график

Делаю проект по биоритмам. Нужно написать код для графика функции. В принципе ничего там сложного нет, но я новичок в Java и знаю я мало.

Функция выглядит следующем образом: `(sin (2pi*t/P))*100`, где pi - число Пи, t - кол-во прожитых дней, а P - коэффициенты которые представлены как константа для всех прожитых дней (их три: 23,28,33), каждый из коэффициентов подставляется в зависимости от того, что нам нужно и все это выражении - либо физический биоритм, либо интеллектуальный, либо духовный. Я думаю формулу, которую я написал выше нужно подставить вместо X. Нашел код в интернете с помощью которого реализуется график (любой), с помощью библиотеки JFreeChart. Если кто знает устраивает ли этот код для моей работы и что нужно корректировать ибо я сам я не могу понять что да как.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;
    public class BioR {
        public int[] p = {23,28,33};
        public double pi = 3.14;
        public static int t = 5000;
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("sin(a)");` `

        for(float i = 0; i < 10; i++){
          series.add(i, Math.sin((Math.PI*t/23)*100));
        }

        XYDataset xyDataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory
            .createXYLineChart("y = sin(x)", "x", "y",
                               xyDataset, 
                               PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                               true, true, true);
        JFrame frame = 
            new JFrame("Физический биоритм");
        // Помещаем график на фрейм
        frame.getContentPane()
            .add(new ChartPanel(chart));
        frame.setSize(800,600);
        frame.show();
      }
    }
```

Comment: это не Swing часом?

Comment: Как видите Swing используется , если я правильно понял о чем вы , но тут в создании графика заложена библиотека JFreeChart

Comment: используйте лучше fx, она новее и по нее больше всего сейчас пишется

Comment: А вас устраивает этот код?